# Render django form multiplechoice

Tags: html, django, forms, render

I have been searching online for how to apply colors/themes to checkbox forms items in django but could not find how to do it.

What I'd like to do is probably easy as pie, but despite all the topics and blogs I red, I still cannot manage to do it.

So here is my forms simplified:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['checkbox'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            label='Set of questions to know you better',
            required=True,
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled'}),
            choices=((1, 'Proposition 1'), (2, 'Proposition 2'), (3, 'Proposition 3'), (4, 'Proposition 4')),
            initial=(1, 2, 4,)
            )
```

And I would like to know how I should modifiy my html which currently looks like

```
<form action="{% url 'dummy' %}" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

</form>
```

so that all choices with an **initial** set to **True** have a given css applied to them and the ones set to **False** another one.

Hope my question makes sense. Please don't hesitate if not.

Best:

Eric

Addition of the current render:
[image]

**EDIT: Addition of the html generated**

```
<form action="/dummy" method="post">

    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='LGZ0mwqrAKxb7CzFvOyYIyUIcDSARy4iwEtHVDjKPpnBd1AIXlk4UyxRuCSIEviY' />
    <p><label>Set of questions to know you better :</label> <ul id="id_checkbox">
    <li><label for="id_checkbox_0"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="1" disabled="disabled" id="id_checkbox_0" checked />
 Proposition 1</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_checkbox_1"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="2" disabled="disabled" id="id_checkbox_1" checked />
 Proposition 2</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_checkbox_2"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="3" disabled="disabled" id="id_checkbox_2" />
 Proposition 3</label>

</li>
    <li><label for="id_checkbox_3"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="4" disabled="disabled" id="id_checkbox_3" checked />
 Proposition 4</label>

</li>
</ul></p>

</form>
```

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Hi. Thanks for your interest. I just added a screenshot of how it looks like at the moment.

Comment: On the screenshot you provided, no checkbox is checked so I guess none has initial set to True. Is it normal ?

Comment: @VaibhavVishal I have juste added the html.

Comment: @May.D You are right. It's not normal. It used to work. I'll have a look at what I might have changed to make it stop working.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal Sorry. My bad. I have just added it.

Comment: Also, do you need to style these inputs (custom css) or add a class like `form-control` ?

Comment: @May.D That would be great indeed. I tried to add form-control at some point, but couldn't make it work properly. By the way, I fixed the issue you raised. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to style checked input, you can just use the CSS pseudo-class `:checked`, in this way:

```
input:checked {
  /*some code here */
}
```

However if you need to conditionally add class to your inputs, you can do it in the view where your instantiate the form and override the `create_option` method, but I think it's easier to create a custom template tag and use it. You can try something like below:

```
from django import template

@register.filter
def add_css(checkbox_input):
    checkbox_input.data['attrs'].update({"class":"your-class"})
    return checkbox_input
```

and then in template

```
{% for x in form.checkbox %}
    {% if x.data.selected %}
        {{ x|add_css }}
    {% else %}
       {{ x }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new Widget based on [CheckboxSelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#CheckboxSelectMultiple), overriding the `create_option` method.

Add a new class attribute if option is selected.

```
def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None):
    [..]
    if selected:
        option_attrs.update(self.checked_attribute)
        # add your class here to option_attrs
    [..]
```

Comment: Looks good. You would put something like what @May.D suggested, ie `checkbox_input.data['attrs'].update({"class":"your-class"})`, where you put your add? Is that right?

Comment: You just need to set: `option_attrs.update({'class': 'yourclass'})`.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thanks for the help.